# Ionic 4 segment mode="md" checked not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, mode, segment

I currently stuck on a ionic 4 segment to get mode="md" working.
I am on version 4.1.2. This is the code:

```
<ion-toolbar text-capitalize>
    <ion-segment mode="md">
      <ion-segment-button value="seg1" text-capitalize checked>
        segment1
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="seg2" text-capitalize>
        segment2
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="seg3" text-capitalize>
        segment3
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

Does anyone has an idea why it isn't working?
When i go on site with Chrome iOS responsive mode i see an iOS-Segment, not an md-segment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the mode md to the toolbar ?

`<ion-toolbar mode="md" text-capitalize>
    <ion-segment mode="md">
      <ion-segment-button value="seg1" text-capitalize checked>
        segment1
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="seg2" text-capitalize>
        segment2
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="seg3" text-capitalize>
        segment3
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>`

Comment: tried, but also looks like iOS on iPhone responsive

Answer (score 0):

You have to change mode to class as below updated code

`<ion-toolbar class="md" text-capitalize>
    <ion-segment class="md">
      <ion-segment-button value="seg1" text-capitalize checked>
        segment1
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="seg2" text-capitalize>
        segment2
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="seg3" text-capitalize>
        segment3
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>`

Globally you can use as below code

`import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      rippleEffect: false,
      mode: 'md'
    }),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  ...
})`

Comment: not working. i still have iOS design, but looks really strange.